# ID Property passed to child changes value

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, react

I'm quite new to lwc's and i'm having an issue where the property passed down to a child component, specifically an ID, the id value in the child component has (-71) appended to the end of the ID. Image supplied is the Id value in the parent component then the id displayed in the child component.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, i was using a variable name of **id** which apparently LWC dont like. I changed the variable to projectId and everything is fine :)

Happy days!